# How do I make this menu stick to the top as it is scrolled past?

Tags: html, css

So im trying to make my menu stick to the top as it is scrolled past, im relatively new and cant figure out how to do it, the menu comes after a video and a site logo, so its positioned down on the website so position: fixed does not work, i guess specificially I want it as i scroll past it, to stay at the top for the rest of the page.

Edit: Solved, thank you to everyone who answered!

Comment: Read into `position: sticky;`.

Comment: Use "position: sticky; top: 0;".

Answer (score 0):

Add position: fixed; to menu div

Or you can add CSS class on page scroll

Comment: Position: fixed; will work but bellow elements will go under it.

Comment: You can add equal padding equal to height. E.g. if your menu has height 50px then add padding bottom to 50 px to div

Comment: So I know fixed positioning usually works, but the menu that im trying to stick to the top does not start at the top of the page, it starts under a site banner and a video, so i want it to stick to the top as it is scrolled passed, position: fixed; kind doesnt work for me, and sticky does not change the page.

Comment: can you share your demo using jsFiddle or codepen?

Answer (score 0):

You could try changing the style into  `position:sticky;`